# Equality of bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

**The Problem:**

Given two fixed vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, which conditions should the matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ fullfill, for the following matrix equation to hold:

$\mathbf{u}^{H}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}^{H}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}$

I suppose there is an infinite space of such matrices, but I would like to know whether this space has some special properties.

Comment: $\bf u$ has to be orthogonal to $(B-A){\bf v}$, so we get a condition on $B-A$. Probably it can be expressed more simply, but I would start from that.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a promising start (I could have realized it myself...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: assume that both vectors $u$ and $v$ are not zero, otherwise any $A$ and $B$ will do.

What you are asking is that the bilinear forms $A$ and $B$ take the same value on the couple $(u,v)$, but this only gives one constraint out of $n^2$ degrees of freedom.

Said differently, your condition says that after some [congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence), $A$ and $B$ must have a common coefficient (one coefficient only, among $n^2$).

Hint: To find the change-of-coordinate matrix, complete $\{u, v\}$ into a basis of the vector space (you need to distinguish two cases according to whether $u$ and $v$ are colinear or not.

Edit: Let's write some details.

**If $u$ and $v$ are collinear:**
Let $P$ be any invertible matrix whose first column is $u$. Consider $A' = P^T\, A \,P$ and $B' = P^T\, B \,P$. 
Then $u^T \, A \, v = u^T \, B \, v$ if and only if $A'_{11} = B'_{11}$.

**If $u$ and $v$ are not collinear:**
Let $P$ be any invertible matrix whose first column is $u$ and second column is $v$. Consider $A' = P^T\, A \,P$ and $B' = P^T\, B \,P$. 
Then $u^T \, A \, v = u^T \, B \, v$ if and only if $A'_{12} = B'_{12}$.

Comment: Thanks! Can I then affirm that the two bilinear forms, for a given couple $\left(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\right)$ take the same value if there is a similarity transformation $\mathbf{P}$ that transforms  $\mathbf{A}$ into $\mathbf{B}$?

Comment: No! Let me edit to clarify that for you.

Comment: The part I do not completely get is when you say "must have a common coefficent".

Comment: Thank you, it is more clear now. Sadly, I expected a more exciting property for $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ than just a single common coefficent.

Comment: That's right, heuristically your constraint only removes one degree of freedom on A and B among $n^2$ degrees of freedom.